# From php page call a python script that opens a visible window

Tags: javascript, php, python

i have this situation:
1) a python script, very basic, that is doing something like:

```
import os

def main():
    p = os.popen('gedit &')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If run by command line it obviously open a gedit visible window.

2) i have a php page that invokes this script, through an ajax request, something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

function test() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/CodeIgniter/application/temp/Test.py",
        success: function(response){
            alert('ok');
        },
        error:function(response) {
            alert("fail");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

When the test() function is invoked (pushing a button for example...), i see the alert ok, but no window is actually opened.
Looking into the list of processes, i see also that 'gedit' process is not present.

Other hint: i am always able to run other python script, and get their json responses (and process them), but if the script is opening some window, i cant see this window.

Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably you have to setup an X tunnel(?) between the webserver processes and your local machine. It isn't so easy. You have to setup a few environment variable. (export DISPLAY=:0) You have to enable the given processes to attach to your Xwindow server. (search around xhost, xauth)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Isn't there a fast way to enable server-x for all users to check if is a permission issue?

Comment: I am not aware of it. Maybe if you start the webserver from your X environment it will inherit the needed permission's. But I think there is a very small chance for this...

Comment: At the end i solved the problem with your first suggestion....i just needed to do:   export DISPLAY=:0